# What is this four-legged part from under an inkjet printer head?

Tags: identification

I've disassembled the print head of an old dried-out printer (EPSON Stylus Photo R300) and found a very small part under it, next to the surface with the nozzles. It's 4 mm long, 3 mm wide and 2.5 mm tall. Here's how it looks from its top (the side farther from the PCB):

[image: top view]

And here's how it looks from the bottom (the side adjacent to the PCB):

[image: bottom view]

In the actual print head it was mounted at the bottom, as if "looking" at the paper. This part seems to look like a pair of IR receivers/transmitters, but the two appear very similar, and I'm not sure why the printer would try to "look" at the paper.

It's definitely not an [optical encoder](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/202767/26112) commonly used to track head position, since that one I've already found and identified, and the part in question was quite far from the striped tape.

So what is this device, and what is its role under the print head?

---

**EDIT** in response to the answer: I've tried supplying some power to the device, and indeed one of them appears to be IR LED:

[image: under power supply]

Comment: Might be to detect whether paper is there or not and/or find its edge so it doesn't print on the roller.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> This part seems to look like a pair of IR receivers/transmitters, but the two appear very similar,

I'd say you are correct. The transmitter is likely to be infrared so it won't be visible to the naked eye but should be [visible to your digital camera / phone](http://lednique.com/test-equipment/test-infrared-led/).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyQ1oo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Test circuit.*

Try to find the IR LED by powering up with a 5 V supply and a 180 Ω resistor. Most LEDs can tolerate 5 V in reverse so you are unlikely to damage it. View it through a camera.

That should leave you with two pins to identify. This is unlikely to be a transistor as shown in my sketch but eliminate that first. With the sensor covered the voltmeter should read 5 V. If the transistor turns on the voltage will drop. You could "drive it hard" using an infrared remote control pointing straight into the receiver.

Note that both lenses will have IR filters and so the receiver will not respond well to visible light.

> ... and I'm not sure why the printer would try to "look" at the paper.

To detect start of page and avoid spraying ink onto the printer itself in the event of a jam or short page.

---

If it's a photo-diode ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXt8Wc.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Photo-diode test circuits.*

- (a) The photo-diode should give a little less than 1 V on diode test function on a digital multimeter.
- (b) This circuit should allow you to detect changes in voltage across the reverse-biased diode when IR is shone on the device.

Comment: It can also be used to detect what width paper is inserted and in machines with out a scanner for basic head alignment.  It's also helpful in edge detection for borderless prints.  I've seen a lot of them be just red leds rather than IR.

Comment: I've now checked easy part — the LED — and it indeed appears to emit IR radiation (posted the photo as an update to the question).

Comment: See the update. Let me know. I've never played with one!

Comment: OK, tried the second part of the component in series with a 4.7kOhm resistor powered by a 5V supply, and was able to see signal from my remote control on the oscilloscope. So it's definitely a photo-diode.

Comment: Cool. Now, can you tell the difference between paper and no paper using the combination of the transmitter and receiver?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed work. At some optimal height (about 1-2 mm, can't measure well from the sheet of paper :) ) the response is at maximum, while directly covered without any spacing it almost doesn't respond. I had to apply considerable current to the LED though, about 100 mA, to make the voltage change easily visible. Anyway, I've accidentally killed the LED, so I can no longer test it :)

Comment: Oops! 20 mA is safe for most LEDs. Well done, anyway. I think you've learned a bit today.